# How to return a group by query via Django REST API?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST API which works perfectly when I want to query some data from the database.
Here I have an example:

**views.py**

```
class ProductListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    def get_queryset(self):
           
        # Collect data from products table and filter it
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(name="Ferrari", date__lte="2022-08-01") # <- Substitute with line below
     
        return queryset
    
    serializer_class       = ProductSerializer
    authentication_classes = [authentication.SessionAuthentication, authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes     = [IsOwnerPermission]
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from insert_data.models import Product

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["name","category","date","price"]
```

The output is what I expect i.e. a json response with the content of the database.

The problems arise when I try to group the queryset in order to return the average price of a product. By doing some research in the internet I noticed that I just need to substitute the line of code in the views.py script with this:

```
Product.objects.filter(name=params['name'], date__lte=query.date).values('name','category').annotate(price_average=Avg('price')).order_by()
```

I am pretty confident that this does the work, however the API returns an error which I do not know how to fix:

> `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pk'`

I totally have no idea what this refers to. Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to return the average price of a product after a group by operation via the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `category` a ForeignKey to a model? I think the problem is with this field in that case.

I believe that when you call `.values()` you get the id of foreignKey-fields and you can't access that field as an object anymore.

So REST Framework is trying to access the property `pk` on what it thinks is an instance of `Category`.

To fix this you can create a custom serializer where `category` is an integer instead and you've added `price_average`. You have to check the field types, I don't know what types you have.

```
class ProductPriceAverageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    category = serializers.IntegerField()
    price_average = serializers.FloatField()
```